# E-commerce Technology using Java

Tags: java, ecommerce

I have not been able to find technology, based in Java, for creating an e-commerce store. I know most of them are using PHP. Is there any using Java language as the backend? Thank you!

Comment: I have problem to find technologogy based in Java, for creating e-commerce store. I know most of them are using PHP. Is there any using java language as backend? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think [Shopizer](http://www.shopizer.com/) is exactly what you are looking for